# process statistics before the invocation of OOM killer in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

I am working on a issue which is related to OOM(out of memory) killer in linux. Root cause of the issue can be found out by the log messages. But i need to check the logs before process termination(kill) happens. I am working on Redhat Linux which is having an utility sos report, will collects the logs after process gets killed. Is there any other utility to get the statistics of a killed process. The one similar to sar utilitiy, which collects the statistics at regular intervals and writes into a file. Is there any other utility available in Redhat linux to collect process statistics which works similar as sar utility?